# querySelectorAll is only selecting the 1st element from the last

Tags: javascript, input, binding, selectors-api

I'm trying to clone AngularJS with my code. What I want is the inputs of ng-models should be binded with their respective  ng-bind.

Here is my **html** code.

```
<body data-ng-app="">
<input ng-model="input">
<p ng-bind="input">1st p element</p>
<p ng-bind="input">2nd p element</p>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the **javascript** file (script.js)

```
'use strict';
/*jshint esversion: 6*/
/*Copyrights HEMANTH ABHIRAM SOMARAJU*/
var i = ['app', 'model', 'bind'].map(l => 'ng-' + l),

    i2 = i.map(l => 'data-' + l);

const fa = (a, b) => a.getAttribute(i[b]) || a.getAttribute(i2[b]),

    fb = (a, b = '', c = document) => c.querySelectorAll(b !== '' ? `*[${i[a]}='${b}'],*[${i2[a]}='${b}']` : `*[${i[a]}],*[${i2[a]}]`);

fb(0).forEach(a => {

    fb(1).forEach(b => {

        fb(2, fa(b, 1), a).forEach(c => b.oninput = () => c.innerText = b.value)

    })

});
```

`What I expected from code is, whenever I give input, then that input text should be binded to the p tags (both). But it is only binding to only first one.`

[image: Sample output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oninput` event-handler binding is functionally wrong here :

```
fb(2, fa(b, 1), a).forEach(c => b.oninput = () => c.innerText = b.value)
```

For each of the `<p>` elements ( variable `c` ), oninput binding on the input element ( variable `b` ) is getting overridden. So, essentially the binding is happening for the last element in the iteration, which is the 2nd `<p>` element in this case.

The binding should happen separately for each of the `<p>` elements, as shown below. Loop over the `<p>` elements as part of the oninput implementation.

```js
fb(0).forEach((a) => {
  fb(1).forEach((b) => {
    return (b.oninput = () => {
      fb(2, fa(b, 1), a).forEach((c) => {
        return (c.innerText = b.value);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After changing oninput event as you said, the code is executing perfectly. But I didn't understood your explanation. Would you please let me know why the previous code didn't worked perfectly?

Comment: In your existing code, you are binding `oninput` to 1st p tag followed by 2nd p tag, inside the `forEach` loop. So, after the loop ends, it is binded to the 2nd p tag. 1st binding is gone. Hence, only 2nd p tag value is getting changed.

Comment: Consider a simple example, where you are changing value of a variable `x` inside a for loop in every iteration. What will be the value of `x` after the loop ends ? It will be the value that is set in the LAST iteration.

Comment: Yeah! Got it. Now I understood. Thanks for solving the mystery in the code.